# Honours Project- sound replacement for a film/short Movie

Tags: movies, replacement, honours

I've just began my final year of university, doing Digital Media with a specialisation in Sound Design and its time to do my honours project and dissertation.

I am to rebuild the sound for a short film, then receive feedback from my supervisor, as well as from the creator/original sound designer for the film.

The main problem im having is that people are ether not replying or are replying no, sadly i have very little time left to find someone who has such a piece that I can work on.

Is there any advice anybody can give me? Ideally looking for a short film, around 10-15 minutes in length, which definitely is available with just dialogue, nothing else. Any recommended websites/people I should speak to?

Thanks In Advanced

Duncan

Answer (score 1):

You could also try checking out mandy.com which regularly advertises opportunities for sound designers in short independent films.  As for dialogue I guess it'll be the luck of the draw as to what is available, and you'll also have to consider what kind of schedule they have vs your submission dates.

I was in a similar predicament during university and ended up contacting the tutors of the film studies/media studies courses to offer my services as a sound designer to any of the final year students there.  I really wanted to design/score some original material and was lucky enough to take on sound designer duties for a short student horror film.  Whilst I don't mean to be negative towards student/independent film makers, you should be aware that it's very possible that you will need to undertake a fair amount of noise reduction and cleaning up of dialogue for these types of projects.  This, however, might actually be beneficial for your project/dissertation in that you will have the opportunity to demonstrate your knowledge of noise-reduction and possibly even ADR.  Also as fellow final year students your deadlines will be similar.

Whatever the case, good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Take a gander at the films available at archive.org  Lots of old stuff there, US social guidance films from the 50s and 60s could be fun to play with. ("As Boys Grow," "Are You Popular," "Boys Beware," etc.) Lots of educational filmstrips from the same time period.

Look at the prelinger archives within archive.org for that material.